# jQuery remove but not container DIV

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
$('#addNote').click(function() {

   var html =
            '<div class="row-fluid" id="notenote"><div class="span9">' +
            $('#noteContent').val() +
            '<input type="hidden" value="' + $('#noteContent').val() + '" name=notes[]>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="span3 ">' +
            '<img width="68" height="60" src="getimage.php?image=current_admin">' +
            '<div class="pull-right">' +
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="removeNote"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>' +
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';

    if ($('#noteContent').val() !== '') {
        $('#noteContent').val('');
        var newnote = $("#noteContainer").append(html);

        newnote.find('.removeNote').on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            newnote.remove();  
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is that when `newnote.remove()` is fired, it deletes also the main container DIV  `#noteContainer`while it should only remove itself, so the DIV `#notenote` and nothing else.
How can I fix this code?

Thanks

Comment: change  newnote.remove();   to $(this).remove()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code:

```
newnote.remove();
```

with this:

```
$(this).closest('#notenote').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply change the content of noteContainer div onclick 
like this

```
$("#noteContainer").html("");
```

Hope it helped...